# What is the use of mongoose methods and statics?

Tags: methods, mongoose, schema

What is the use of mongoose methods and statics and how are they different from normal functions?

Can anyone explain the difference with example.

Answer (score 58):

Database logic should be encapsulated within the data model. Mongoose provides 2 ways of doing this, methods and statics. **Methods** adds an instance method to documents whereas **Statics** adds static "class" methods to the Models itself.

Given the example **Animal** Model below:

```js
var AnimalSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  type: String,
  hasTail: Boolean
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Animal', AnimalSchema);
```

We could add a method to find similar types of animal, and a static method to find all animals with tails:

```js
AnimalSchema.methods.findByType = function (cb) {
  return this.model('Animal').find({ type: this.type }, cb);
};

AnimalSchema.statics.findAnimalsWithATail = function (cb) {
  Animal.find({ hasTail: true }, cb);
};
```

Here's the full model with example usage for methods and statics:

```js
var AnimalSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  type: String,
  hasTail: Boolean
});

AnimalSchema.methods.findByType = function (cb) {
  return this.model('Animal').find({ type: this.type }, cb);
};

AnimalSchema.statics.findAnimalsWithATail = function (cb) {
  Animal.find({ hasTail: true }, cb);
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('Animal', AnimalSchema);

// example usage:

var dog = new Animal({
  name: 'Snoopy',
  type: 'dog',
  hasTail: true
});

dog.findByType(function (err, dogs) {
  console.log(dogs);
});

Animal.findAnimalsWithATail(function (animals) {
  console.log(animals);
});
```

Answer (score 10):

If i wanted to retrieve animals with `hasTail` i could simply change this line of code:

```
return this.model('Animal').find({ type: this.type }, cb);
```

to:

```
return this.model('Animal').find({ hasTail: true }, cb);
```

and i would not have to create a statics function.

Use method on individual documents if you want to manipulate the individual document like adding tokens etc.
Use the statics approach if you want query the whole collection.

Comment: That's a good answer. I don't know what's great in copying and pasting the documentation :). You've got directly to the point.